# Blazor local storage SetItemAsync has race condition across pages

Tags: local-storage, blazor, identityserver4, webassembly

[https://code-maze.com/how-to-secure-blazor-webassembly-with-identityserver4/]

[https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage]

I have a Blazor WASM utilising IdentityServer4 (above guide) which use local storage as well.

In my "RemoteAuthenticatorView", I have hooked both OnLogInSucceeded & OnLogOutSucceeded events.
The respective events will perform SetItemAsync & ClearAsync with local storage where there are some extra user details. User details is for the purpose of doing some minor data retrieval if required.

There are 2 issues right now

1. LocalStorage.SetItemAsync is not fast enough as when the sub pages is initialized, the read from local storage will yield empty result. All storage retrieve is done in OnInitializedAsync of the Razor pages.
2. The OnLogOutSucceeded event does not trigger therefore LocalStorage.ClearAsync is not called. A subsequent login with diff credential will retrieve previously stored user detail

```
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="SetClaimsPrincipalData" OnLogOutSucceeded="ClearClaimsPrincipalData">
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

private async Task SetClaimsPrincipalData()
{
    try
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var loggedInAccount = UserData.GetClaimsValue(user);
            var loggedInAccountStr = JsonHelper.SerializeString(loggedInAccount);

            await this.localStorage.ClearAsync();
            await this.localStorage.SetItemAsync(DisplayConfigs.SessionStorageKeyUserData, loggedInAccountStr);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private async Task ClearClaimsPrincipalData()
{
    try
    {
        await this.localStorage.ClearAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

//=====//

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var savedUserDataString = await this.localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>(KeyUserData);
        this.loggedInAccount = JsonHelper.DeserializeString<LoggedInAccount>(savedUserDataString);

        //// Base init
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex, ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: *Don't* use `async void`. Your methods aren't awaited. `async void` is only meant for asynchronous *desktop* events. Use `async Task` for async methods without a return value. All Blazor examples and tutorials use `async Task`

Comment: Well, I did simplify the code a bit for posting. It is using async Task actually.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I have edited back to original code.

So the (1st point) race condition is resolved, that leaves the event trigger. 
Can I say that in order for the log out event to trigger, the Tab page must remain in pointed to the same 'website' and not like getting redirected to 'google.com'?

My Blazor connects to IdentityServer4 for authen & author. On log out, I get re-directed to the IdentityServer4 index page instead of Blazor index page. I am starting to suspect this is the issue related issue point 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I run into a race condition with local or session storage I end up making a service that holds/accesses the data. The service uses a bool flag `isInitialized` and instead of directly accessing the storage I wait for the flag to be `true` before reading the data.

```
public bool isInitialized = false;
public async Task SetClaimsPrincipalData()
{
    // Set LocalStorage
    // .
    // .
    // .
    isInitialized = true;

}

public async Task<string> GetClaimsPrincipalData()
{
    while (!isInitialized) { await Task.Delay(100); }
    return await this.localStorage.GetAsync<string>(DisplayConfigs.SessionStorageKeyUserData);
}
```

Now when you call `GetClaimsPrincipalData` it must wait for `SetClaimsPrincipalData` to be completed before returning.

Comment: So as per your suggestion, it is working fine now. I also added a maximum delay before I break out of the while loop to prevent an indefinite wait.